# Why are new users named 'user123' when the signup form has a 'public display name'?

Tags: bug, status-completed, accounts, display-names

Why do new users not get named with the display name they give in the signup form?

I just created a new Stack Overflow account to see the current flow, and I dilligently provided name, email and password in the form below.

[image: The signup form]

However the `Name (your public display name)` field was ignored, and when the profile was created it looked like this:

[image: What the virgin profile looks like]

Is there a design reason for why the *Name* field is ignored, and if so why is it asked for in the sign up form?

Comment: Hmmm... it does seem like that field should be what shows up there. Looks wrong...

Comment: @AndrewBarber -- not sure I understand your comment -- do you mean that you expect the 'Name' field (first field) to show up as the username?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, that was worded clumsily! I mean I expected the same thing you do.

Comment: Probably from the OAuth providers where you don't (afaik) need to fill this out.

Comment: Taking a look at this

Comment: @Joe -- I didn't use any of the OAuth providers, but when through creating the account directly with stackexchange.

Comment: Th OAUTH providers are all (afaik) all returning a "Full Name" -- the public display name should just default to that when a user signs up with OAuth.

Comment: @Soren that makes sense, it was a guess so the full name thing sounds reasonable. Guess this is potentially a bug then!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report. This bug was twofold: an issue in the Open ID provider code, combined with an issue in the Stack Exchange site code checking the validity of a display name. Both have now been corrected and your display name will carry through upon registration. This will be live in the next prod release.